# laravel 5.4 access current user data in layout.blade

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to get data about the current user in the header of the site, what would be displayed on each page! 
I tried to use:

`{{Auth :: user () -> name}}`

but only works on the login page. 
When I go to another page, 
I get an error: "*Trying to get property of non-object*". 
How to fix it?

Comment: try removing your curly braces. `Auth :: user () -> name`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I seem to have found a mistake. The thing is that not all routes are protected by middleware

Comment: Add `auth` middleware to that routes which is open only after user are logged in.

Answer (score -1):

Try this piece of code:

`\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->name == 'specfied name'`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.